# Implement a FIFO list in C

Tags: c, arrays, fifo

I am a newbie programmer and i need some help.
I am trying to implement a FIFO list in C (not C++ nor C#). This is how i defined struct

```
typedef struct node *link;

struct node{ 
    Item item; 
    link next; 
};
```

I am trying to add node to my list with this function.

```
void add(Item newItem, link head, link tail)
{   link helper; 
    helper = malloc(sizeof(link));
    helper -> item = newItem;
    if (head == NULL){  
        head = helper;
        tail = helper;
    }
    else{
        tail -> next = helper;
        tail = helper;
        }
}
```

But when I use the function showItem(tail -> item); in main i get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Then use a debugger. Also, don't hide pointers in typedefs. (The reason why not: likely you meant `malloc(sizeof(*helper))` instead of `sizeof(link)`...)

Comment: Also, you should check the return of `malloc`. Glad you're not casting it at least ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you allocate the node, use the size of node, not of the pointer

```
 helper = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

it is often better not to typedef pointers as it makes them difficult to see in various contexts, instead typedef the struct node

```
 typedef struct node 
 { 
   Item data;
   struct node* next;
 } node;
```

then its clear when it is a node* and when not.

Comment: also, `malloc(sizeof *helper)`, because redundancy will hurt you if you ever change the type of `helper`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also you were amazingly fast.